# SQL Query returning incorrectly formatted data even though the function is returning the correct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The data in my table represents physical locations with the following data: A municipality name, a state(province/region), and a unique ID which is comprised of a prefix and postfix separated by a dash (all NVARCHAR).

| Name | State | UniqueID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Atlanta | Georgia | A12-1383 |

The dash in the UniqueID is not always in the same position (can be A1-XYZ, A1111-XYZ, etc.). The postfix will always be numerical.

My approach is using a combination of `RIGHT` and `CHARINDEX` to first find the index of the dash and then isolate the postfix to the right of the dash, and then applying a `MAX` to the result. My issue so far has been that this combination is sometimes returning things like `-1234` or `12-1234`, i.e, including the dash and occasionally some of the prefix. Because of this, the max is obviously applied incorrectly.

Here is my query thus far:

```
select name, max(right(uniqueid,(Charindex('-',uniqueid)))) as 'Max'
from locations
where state = 'GA' and uniqueid is not NULL
group by name
order by name ASC
```

This is what the results look like for the badly formatted rows:

| Name | Max |
| --- | --- |
| Atlanta | 11-2442 |
| Savannah | -22 |

This is returning incorrectly formatted data for 'Max', so I isolated the functions.

`CHARINDEX` is correctly returning the position of the dash, including in cases where the function is returning badly formatted data. Since the dash is never in the same place, I cannot isolate the `RIGHT` function to see if that is the problem.

Am I using these functions incorrectly? Or is my approach altogether incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: You've just untagged SQL Server, but MySQL doesn't have a `charindex` function...

Comment: Are you looking for the max unique id (numeric part only) for each name ?

Comment: @DaleK I untagged the wrong one, I am correcting this now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHARINDEX` is counting how many chars before the `-` i.e. how many chars on the *left hand side*, so using `RIGHT` with the number of chars on the *left* isn't going to work. You need to find out how many chars are on the *right* which can be done with `LEN()` to get the total length less the number of chars on the left.

```
SELECT RIGHT(MyColumn,LEN(MyColumn)-CHARINDEX('-',MyColumn))
FROM (
    VALUES
    ('A12ssss-1383'),
    ('A12-13834'),
    ('A12ss-138')
) X (MyColumn);
```

Comment: This solved my issue, which was that I was misunderstanding the parameters for RIGHT. I am now running into formatting issues with data that has a carriage return at the end, but that is a beyond the scope of this. Thank you!